# What do the numbers that appear when Interceptor "blocks" indicate?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

In Final Fantasy 6, the character Shadow can occasionally "block" an attack completely via his weapon (like many characters) but also via his dog, Interceptor. This dog occasionally counter-attacks for large amounts of damage, which is what it is famous for.

However, some of the time when Shadow is blocking, a number appears next to the "blocking-dog-parry" sprite that appears adjacent to Shadow.  It appears with the same font color (white) that usually indicates damage to a character, but Shadow's HP is not affected and as far as I know, Interceptor doesn't have HP.  This number does not always seem to appear during these dog-blocks.

*What does this number mean?*

(Bonus points for information specific to [Brave New World](http://www.insanedifficulty.com/board/index.php?/topic/7485-brave-new-world-174-is-now-available/), which is the version of FF6 I'm currently playing.)

Comment: Could be this? From [FF wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Interceptor_(Final_Fantasy_VI)): "If Shadow is attacked physically, there is a chance Interceptor will take the hit for Shadow, and thus how much damage Shadow could have taken will be displayed."

Comment: @pinckerman the damage is considerably lower than the damage Shadow has been taken during the hits he and his dog fail to block, so I don't think so.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @pinckerman Yes, I'll add one when I have a chance (which won't be soon, but will eventually happen!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Interceptor blocking uses the same code as when Golem blocks, I believe. Damage taken does matter there, since Golem will only block so much damage before it goes away (vanilla = caster's current HP | BNW = caster's max HP).

It also shows that Interceptor is a bigger badass than most of your characters.

Comment: Ah so the damage is lower on the dog because his defense is much higher than Shadow's, right?

Comment: Everyone's defense is higher than Shadow's >.>